# What do functions prod, cast and shape from keras.backend?

Tags: keras

I have not found a description of how any function works in the official documentation. More specifically, I'm interested in how the processing of the tensor `x` in the third line will take place.

```
from keras import backend as K

some_type = 'float32'
y = K.prod(K.cast(K.shape(x), some_type))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the documentation [here](https://faroit.com/keras-docs/1.2.0/backend/#:%7E:text=What%20is%20a%20%22backend%22%3F,products%2C%20convolutions%20and%20so%20on.)

Then for what I see,

```py
y = K.prod(K.cast(K.shape(x), some_type))
```

For a tensor x, you cast the shape of x in float32, then you multiply those values.